# Unable to load images from image urls in App Notification Widget

Tags: ios, notifications, widget

I am trying to show list of images in a collection view inside App Notification Widget.
Its giving me the error "Unable to load" if I am loading from urls, other than its working fine. 
Can anyone please help me in this ?

```
TodaysCusCell *catTrendingCusCell = (TodaysCusCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"TodaysCusCellID" forIndexPath:indexPath];
NSDictionary *trendingDic = (NSDictionary *)[trendingArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

//Loading Images
NSString *imageURL = [trendingDic objectForKey:@"image_url"];
[catTrendingCusCell.trendingImgView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageURL] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"grayBackground"]];
```

Comment: Image url having http or https? If it is http, then you need to add "App Transport Security Settings" in info.plist file.

Comment: No its https type. I think its due to memory issue.